# How to programmatically use attribute values in code

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, themes

I'm migrating a project to Jetpack Compose and there are a number of instances where values of syntax "?attrs/" are used to define dimensions in XML. How do I access those values in Kotlin code to provide them to Jetpack Compose declarations?

Answer (score 1):

If you define the `attr` as:

```
   <attr name="customDimension" format="dimension"/>
```

and in the theme used by the Activity is defined:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">  
    <item name="customDimension">16dp</item>
</style>
```

In your composable you can get this value using:

```
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val typedValue = context.getDimensionFromAttrs(R.attr.customDimension)
    val dimension = typedValue.getDimension(context.resources.displayMetrics)
```

with this extension:

```
fun Context.getDimensionFromAttrs(attr: Int): TypedValue {
    return TypedValue().apply {
        theme.resolveAttribute(attr, this, true)
    }
}
```

Then you can just use it:

```
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    Button(
        onClick = { /* doSomething */ },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(density.run { dimension.toDp()})
    ){
      //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following to get resources:

`val res = LocalContext.current.resources`

Then you can use `res` to getDimension(YourID), and convert to dp

```kotlin
val myDimension = res.getDimension(R.attr.something).myDimension.dp
```